# ruby regex for two backslashes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find a regex that matches any string with two consecutive backslashes.  I'm trying every variation, any help? And info on handling backslashes

```
b='\\mystring'

if b=~/\\\\/
  puts "it matches"
end
```

I can't seem to get this to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex looks good, but your string does NOT contain two backslashes, it just contains one.  It looks like it contains two but that's only in your source file, not in the actual string.  Try this:

```
'\\\\mystring' =~ /\\\\/
```

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is still a bit magic even inside hard `'` quotes. For one thing, it needs to be able to quote `'` itself, and so what if your string had a `\` followed by `'`? You need to be able to backslash-quote the backslash in order to unambiguously get a single `\` before a magic character, and for sanity, everywhere else as well.

```
>> '\\'.length
=> 1
>> '\''
=> "'"
>> '\\'[1,1]
=> ""
>> '\\'[0,1]
=> "\\"
```

Comment: thx for further clarification